# UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor does not work with custom color in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I try to tint my tab bar color to a test color as the following commented code (where it says "this does not work". Certainly, i have tried other colors) to no avail.

[image: c]

This is when I set the tint to system colors such as red.

[image: a]

This is when I tried to use custom color, nothing happens.
[image: b]

Is this an error from my side? How to solve? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:140.0/255, green:200.0/255, blue:219.0/255, alpha:1)
```

Comment: Yep, you've got to assign the values as x/255

Comment: x(float)/255, don´t forget. This 222/255 don´t work.